# Permission Denial with Contacts in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to access the contacts and display them, but it won't let me, it denies me access...i already read others answsers in this website but still with the error...I already gave the permissions in a properly way.

this is the code:

```
    TextView contactView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactview);
    Cursor cursor = getContacts();

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactView.append("Name: ");
        contactView.append(displayName);
        contactView.append("\n");
    }
     //End of onCreate

    private Cursor getContacts(){

    //runs the query

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID ,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" + ("1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder);
}
```

This is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pc.contentprovider">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And the Log:

```
01-17 23:12:33.250 10142-10142/com.example.pc.contentprovider E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.pc.contentprovider, PID: 10142                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pc.contentprovider/com.example.pc.contentprovider.ContactsActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{5150ff8 10142:com.example.pc.contentprovider/u0a57} (pid=10142, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{5150ff8 10142:com.example.pc.contentprovider/u0a57} (pid=10142, uid=10057) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
                                                                                at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
                                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
                                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
                                                                                at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                                                at com.example.pc.contentprovider.ContactsActivity.getContacts(ContactsActivity.java:60)
                                                                                at com.example.pc.contentprovider.ContactsActivity.onCreate(ContactsActivity.java:25)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
01-17 23:13:12.640 10142-10142/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10142 SIG: 9
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023674/android-6-getaccountname-missing-android-permission-get-accounts/33023784#33023784

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Android Studio, check your gradle.build file and see what version of Android you are targeting.

If it is 23 then you need to use the new Marshmallow permissions system.

If you set the TARGET to 21 and lower it will use the now older manifest declared permission system, which asks the user on App Install for all permissions at once. This will work on Android 6 devices too.

I would encourage you to work to the former rather than the latter, as this is the newer method of requesting permissions.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Android is this run on?
In Android 6.0 you have to request permissions in code.
You can check if this is the problem looking for this application in phone settings and giving it permissions it needs manually.

Comment: i'm running it on an android emulator Api 23 Android 6.0, how can i add permissions in code??

Comment: Look here:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html also check other questions here for details.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 6.0 the permission model has changed, now you need to ask the user for permission at Run time . Look at this google sample which explains how to request for Contact permissions [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions).  Read through this developer notes [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

If you are running for Android API version less than 23 then the older way which you have listed works. For anything above and equal to API version 23, you need to request Permission at Run time.

There are two types of permission defined from API version 23, one with PROTECTION_NORMAL and one without. The PROTECTION_NORMAL permissions still work the old way example accessing network state and Internet, which do not do much Harm. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/normal-permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the new permission for [newer versions of android](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) (6.0+).

Here is some examples from the site:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```